# How to rename the file

Tags: magento-1.9

How to rename the image file name before upload **database** and **Media** Folder

```
 public function fanbookAction(){
        $img = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('img');
                if(isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) 
                {
                    try{
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
                        $destFile = $path.'/'.str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['img']['name']);
                        $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $uploader->save($path, $filename);
                        $img ='FanBook/'.$filename;
                        $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
                        $collection ->setData('img',$img);
                        $collection->save();

                        $this->_redirectReferer();
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Request has been Completed Successfully');
                    }

                    catch(Exception $e) {

                    }


                }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$filename` variable to your required custom name, after this line :

```
...  

$filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);

$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //getting image extension
$filename = "YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME.".$ext; //change custom name here
...
```

Comment: What i needs to add ?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: is it correct  $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                        $ext = pathinfo($filename, $path.$uploader); //getting image extension
                        $filename = "custom.".$ext; //change custom name here

Comment: extension not storing

Comment: This is wrong `$ext = pathinfo($filename, $path.$uploader);`, use same as I have shown  `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`.

Comment: How to get extension path it's working fine only problem is extension

Comment: This line is for getting image extensions `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`  (like jpg, png  etc..). Just put it as is

Comment: ya tha's what i told $path getting extact path then how i get EXTENSION

Comment: Can you just use the EXACT code, `without changing ANYTHING`. And check if it uploads image named YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39375/discussion-between-anil-suthar-and-kothari).